# Google Mock, expect call between 2 given numbers

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I'm using google mock as a framework for testing a real time system, I want to verify that the configuration to the sensors is being implemented correctly. To do that I am sending a new Frequency to said sensor and expecting my sensor data callback to be called x number of times.

Due to this I have to sleep the testing thread for a few seconds, so my callback can be called a few times.

Due to this the expected calls are not a set number, for example, if I expect my callback to be called once per second and I sleep the thread 5 seconds, it can actually be called between 4 and 6 times, otherwise the test would be too restrictive.

This is the problem, I haven't found a way to test if expect call is between 4 and 6, I tried the following:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AnyNumber());
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AtMost(6));
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AtLeast(4));
```

And

```
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AnyNumber());
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AtLeast(4));
EXPECT_CALL(*handler,Data_Mock(_,_)).Times(::testing::AtMost(6));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Between` from https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#cardinalities-cardinalitylist. It is exactly for the purpose of asserting that given call be called between `m` and `n` times.

Comment: Damn, I was looking so many keywords on those docs and for some reason I didn't think of searching that one, thx it worked perfectly :D